# In C#, how do you get recursive value equality for nested anonymous arrays and objects?

Tags: c#

**Note:** For `Assert`, using Xunit

Anonymous objects use value equality:

```
Assert.Equal(
  new { foo = "bar" },
  new { foo = "bar" }
);
```

Anonymous arrays with anonymous objects use value equality:

```
Assert.Equal(
  new [] { new { foo = "bar" } },
  new [] { new { foo = "bar" } }
);
```

Anonymous objects with nested arrays seem to use reference equality (this fails):

```
Assert.Equal(
  new { baz = new [] { new { foo = "bar" } },
  new { baz = new [] { new { foo = "bar" } }
);
```

But this works (presumably because there's now reference equality):

```
var baz = new [] { new { foo = "bar" } };
Assert.Equal(
  new { baz },
  new { baz }
);
```

And this works (so it appears I can recursively nest anonymous objects with value equality preserved):

```
Assert.Equal(
  new { baz = new { qux = new { foo = "bar" } } },
  new { baz = new { qux = new { foo = "bar" } } }
);
```

I'm not sure how equality is being conducted here, but I'd like to be able to nest objects and arrays and have infinite-depth value equality. How might I go about doing that?

**Update**

Looks like [Fluent Assertions](https://fluentassertions.com/) solved my problem (this test passes):

```
(new { baz = new[] { new { foo = "bar" } } })
    .Should()
    .BeEquivalentTo(new { baz = new [] { new { foo = "bar" } } });
```

Comment: IMO, in your 3rd example `baz` is a reference to an array which would use `ReferenceEqual()` for comparison resulting in a mismatch. However, in your 4th example, both references refer to the same object (the underlying array) which would make it pass the equality test whether you used value equality or reference equality.

Comment: @MickyD Good point, added a bit more clarification about what I was saying worked (or didn't).

Comment: Thank-you Andrew

Comment: There's no such thing as an "anonymous array". It's just type inference for a normal array.

Comment: Please specify which testing framework you're using - because for the array examples, it's *that* which is checking for equality. If you just use `x.Equals(y)` you'll get different answers.

Comment: What library do you use for `Assert.Equal`?

Comment: @DaisyShipton Added clarification about using Xunit -- thanks!

Comment: @GhasanAl-Sakkaf Added clarification about using Xunit -- thanks!

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm relatively new to C#... wouldn't that type inference, if the array was composed of anonymous type objects, have a type of the anonymous class? Might be semantics, what would you call that array? An array of anonymously-typed objects?

Comment: @Andrew - You're right - it's an array of anonymously-typed objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use [FluentAssertions](https://fluentassertions.com/) nuget package. It will let you compare any objects and collections by properties including nested objects/collections, like :

```
result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
```

It also has extensive options, allowing you to compare by runtime type instead of compile time type, or to exclude certain properties from comparison.

Example of respecting runtime type, should work for those anonymous objects:

```
result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, options => 
    options.RespectingRuntimeTypes());
```

Comment: Interesting, this might actually be the answer as it seems like I want the assertion library I use to check for value equality... Thanks!

I'll try this library out and select yours as the answer if it works! Thanks again!

Comment: Chose this as the answer because it answered the question I had. All the other answers were great in explaining why I was having the problem, but appreciate the recommendation for an assertion library that gets around the `Equals` problem with enumerable reference types!

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 2):

For anonymous types, their `Equal` and `GetHashCode` implementation is the result of recursively running `Equal` or `GetHashCode` on their properties. So if you have two anonymous classes with similar value-type properties with the same values, then they compare as equal.

However, if any property is a reference-type, and it does not point to the same object, then they won't be equal.

Here is the snippet from Microsoft docs [[1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types):

> Because the Equals and GetHashCode methods on anonymous types are defined in terms of the Equals and GetHashCode methods of the properties, two instances of the same anonymous type are equal only if all their properties are equal.

Now, as why arrays are equal, I would bet it is the Assert.Equal implementation that checks if the objects are enumerable, then it check their items equality.

Comment: Interesting! So it sounds like what I'm hoping would have happened is that the `Equals` Microsoft would have implemented for anonymous types would have acted by recursively checking for value equality and, when a reference type was encountered, checking if that reference type is enumerable and iteratively checking for value equality over it's members.

Since it seems like it doesn't (it checks for reference equality), I'm getting the failing assertion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The generated Equals method of an anonymous object compare it's fields one by one with a default comparer (EqualityComparer.Default)

This comparer uses Equals method to compare objects, so for arrays it compares the references.

Because anonymous object cannot implement any interface, if you want to keep 2 anonymous objects equality, you may write anonymous object only, or use your 4th example to include arrays.

About the 2nd example, the 2 arrays are equal because the library implements [the comparsion method](https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/blob/f35089f4ddc7ac3eb11ea460fbc3dd17ea8ddd7a/Sdk/AssertEqualityComparer.cs#L114).

Comment: Thanks @shingo, this is thorough yet concise explanation!